# Orgmode: is it possible to set tags at a file level?

Tags: org-mode

Having a file for a particular project, I would like all the nodes in that file to have a tag identifying the project, so that I can later use it to create agenda views for that project only. So far all I've found is `#+TAGS: foo bar spam` which specifies a hard list of tags offered in tag autocompletion for that file.

Does anyone know of a `#+XXX`-like instruction to achieve this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes. From the [Tag inheritance](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tag-Inheritance.html) chapter of the `org-mode` manual (emphasis mine):

> Tags make use of the hierarchical structure of outline trees. If a heading has a certain tag, all subheadings will inherit the tag as well. For example, in the list
>
> ```
> * Meeting with the French group      :work:
> ** Summary by Frank                  :boss:notes:
> *** TODO Prepare slides for him      :action:
> ```
>
> the final heading will have the tags `:work:`, `:boss:`, `:notes:`, and `:action:` even though the final heading is not explicitly marked with those tags. **You can also set tags that all entries in a file should inherit** just as if these tags were defined in a hypothetical level zero that surrounds the entire file. Use a line like this:
>
> ```
> #+FILETAGS: :Peter:Boss:Secret:
> ```

Comment: Great, I found the answer immediately after posting the question, and wrote an answer myself but you beat me to it ;)
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @ElNinjaTrepador Yes - by 12 seconds :) However, I'm happy you were able to answer your own question!

Answer (score 13):

File specific tags can be specified as:

```
#+FILETAGS: :tag1:tag2:tag3:
```

These tags then apply to lower level entries through inheritance.

Answer (score 11):

Okay, I found the answer to the question right after posting it... anyway, here it goes for those who might not know how to do this:

```
#+FILETAGS: :foo:bar:spam:
```

Found the info in [this](https://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-Settings.html) very useful page with all the in-buffer settings.